# How to extract the part of a text file after the second occurrence of a specific word using Python

Tags: python, regex, text, extract, analysis

I am trying to extract the part of a text file after the second occurrence of a specific word till to end of again second occurrence of another specific word. The reason is that these two words are stated at first in the table of contents. Therefore when I run the code I got 0 output of the first occurences.

Sample text:

Table of contents

Item 1a.Risk Factors

- not any text (unwanted portion)

Item 1b

End of table of contents

Main content
Item 1a. Risk Factors

- text (wanted portion)
- text (wanted portion)
- text (wanted portion)

Item 1b

I need the extract the text between the second occurrence of Item 1a. Risk Factors and the second occurrence of Item 1b.

My code below:

```
for file in tqdm(files):
with open(file, encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == 'Item 1A.Risk Factors': 
            break
    for line in f: 
        if line.strip() == 'Item 1B':
            break
f=open(os.path.join('QTR4_Risk_Factors',
os.path.basename(file)) , 'w')
f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: Do you want to return the text that is after the second occurrence of `Item 1a. Risk Factors` and before the *first* occurrence of `Item 1b` that follows `Item 1a. Risk Factors`? If so, that's not what you asked for. In your example the first `Item 1b` is before the first occurrence of `Item 1a. Risk Factors`, but if `Item 1b` had not preceded `Item 1a. Risk Factors` we would be looking for the second occurrence of `Item 1b` following `Item 1a. Risk Factors`.

Comment: I just would like to extract the portion of text between the second occurrence of Item1A and the second occurrence of Item 1B.

Comment: It follows that you wish to return an empty string (or a failure of some sort) if the second instance of `Item 1b` occurs before the first instance of `Item 1a`. Does the answer you selected do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with the code you wrote, one of each is that you do not save the part of text you need while scanning the document looking for the "end text". Also it is best practice to store as little of the text in memory, if possible, because we don't know how big the document you are trying to analyze is. To do that we can write to the new file while we are reading the original.

Ronie's answer is going in the right direction but it doesn't address the fact that you want to start saving the text only after the second occurrence of your "start hint". Unfortunately I am not yet able to comment to suggest the edit, so I am adding it as a new answer.
Try this:

```
for file in tqdm(files):
    with open(file, encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f, open(os.path.join('QTR4_Risk_Factors', os.path.basename(file)) , 'w') as w:
        start_hint_counter = 0
        write = False
        for line in f:
            if write is False and line.strip() == 'Item 1A.Risk Factors': 
                start_hint_counter += 1
                if start_hint_counter == 2:
                    write = True
            if write is True:
                if line.strip() == 'Item 1B':
                    break
                else:
                    w.write(line)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. The code runs properly. I have another question related with this. In some files, there is Item 1B, for some there is not and it follows Item 2. How can I add a this situation into the code?

Comment: @volkanarslan a naive approach is to simply add more conditions to that if.
`if line.strip() == 'Item 1B':` can become `if line.strip() == 'Item 1B or line.strip() == 'Item 2':`
If you want to add many more options there can be better approaches.

Comment: Works well. One last question:) This code looks lines if there is only 'Item 1B' or 'Item 2', it stops. However if there is any other text after the keywords such as Item 2. XXX, it continues to extract. Thanks again

Comment: You can use `if line.startswith('Item 1B')` if you want to look for something at the beginning of the line, or more generically `if 'Item 1B' in line`. Check out the [Python reference documentation on string manipulation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), is very useful

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a flag to know when to copy the lines. Also you can open 2 or more files at the same time in a context manager.

```
with open(file, encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f, open(os.path.join('QTR4_Risk_Factors', os.path.basename(file)) , 'w') as w:
    write = False
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == 'Item 1A.Risk Factors': 
            write = True
            continue
        elif line.strip() == 'Item 1B':
            write = False
        if write == True:
            w.write(line)
```

> Ronie's answer is going in the right direction but it doesn't address the fact that you want to start saving the text only after the second occurrence of your "start hint".

EDIT: Added `continue`

Comment: Thanks. Now It starts extracting from the 1st occurrence of 'Item 1A' till to 2nd occurrence of Item 1B.

Answer (score 0):

You could try regex:

```
import re

t = """Item 1a.Risk Factors

not any text (unwanted portion)
Item 1b

End of table of contents

Main content
Item 1a. Risk Factors

text (wanted portion)
text (wanted portion)
text (wanted portion)
Item 1b"""

crit = re.compile('Item 1a.Risk Factors.*?Item 1a. Risk Factors(.*?)Item 1b', re.I|re.DOTALL)
if re.search(crit, t):
    result = re.search(crit, t).group(1)
```